# Is it possible to delete a tag?

Tags: support, tags, retagging

There are tags that are misspelled and should be renamed. For the time being the only solution I found is to re-tag all the question with the tag of the correct spelling.

I end up with tags associate with no questions that should be deleted.

Is there are a way to delete a tag that has no questions?

Is there a way to rename a tag?

Comment: I’ll find out if there’s a way for us to delete tags if need be; I think the right path would be Meta post -> tag deletion. But otherwise let the vacuum bot handle it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tag without any questions should be automatically deleted by the Roomba bot.

I think the mods have a way to rename tags, if not directly, then they can pass it up to a staff member.

Comment: I confirm that after 1 day the astrovim tag that I replaced by the astronvim one and that had no more question has been deleted.